# Making a 3D cylinder out of a polygon

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I have a polygon which I would like to convert to a cylindrical 3D object for an illustration:

```
x <- structure(list(x = c(7.99, 6.25, -1.77, -1.8, -0.48, 3.93, 7.99
), y = c(2.84, 2.31, 2.43, 2.98, 3.19, 3.26, 2.84)), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")

plot(x$x, x$y, type = "n")
polygon(x$x, x$y, col = "blue")
points(x$x, x$y)
```

[image]

I cannot get my head around how to add z-axis with values 2 and 5 for example:

```
library(rgl)
lines3d(x = rep(x$x, 2), y = rep(x$y, 2), z = rep(c(2, 5), each = nrow(x)))
```

[image]

I would like to make the faces colored and connected. Something like the [cylinders on Wikipedia illustrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder), but naturally not round ends, but those polygons instead. [`tringles3d`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder) or `polygon3d` functions are probably what I should use if I used the rgl package, but I don't understand how to restructure my data.frame. I do not need to do this in rgl. That was just the R package which seemed most feasible for this task. How should I reorganize my data to plot the 3D cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `extrude3d` to create an "extrusion" of your polygon.
For example, with `x` as defined in the question,

```
x[-1,] %>% 
  extrude3d(thickness = 3, material = list(col = rainbow(14)),
            meshColor = "faces") %>%
  translate3d(x = 0, y = 0, z = 2) %>%
  shade3d()
```

produces this image (after some manual rotation):

[image: screenshot]

It uses `x[-1,]`, because you repeated the first vertex at the end:  it wants unique vertices.

The coloring is kind of funny:  to draw the hexagons on each end, `rgl` draws 4 triangles, and each is treated as a separate face for the purpose of coloring.  If you want solid colors there, remember that the ends are drawn first:  so use something like

```
material = list(col = rainbow(8)[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2:8)])
```

instead.

The other funny argument to `extrude3d` is `thickness`:  the polyhedron is drawn between `z=0` and `z=thickness`.  Since you wanted `z` from 2 to 5, the `thickness` is 3, and the result needs to be translated up 2 units in z.

There's also `cylinder3d`, which is used for generating tubular structures, but `extrude3d` is simpler to use if you only want your polygon to show up in two places at right angles to the sides.